# getting value from key as id name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, key-value

I am waiting for a number from server, once I get the number, I want to find an according id name to change the background of that div.

So, I created a set of key and value

```
var timelineKeys = {
        "4": "btn_no_1",
        "5": "btn-no-2",
        "6": "btn-no-3",
        "7": "btn-no-4",
        "1": "btn-no-5",
        "2": "btn-no-6",
        "2": "btn-no-7",
    }
```

in my $.ajax, I get the variable from server and I call it 't', 't' will be one of the key numbers there, but how can I get text "btn-no-.." dynamically using this variable? timelineKeys.t seems doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like `t['4']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timelinekeys[t]
```

is the syntax when the property name you want to access is contained in a variable, `t` in your case; for more information refer to this question: [Difference between using bracket (`[]`) and dot (`.`) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation/)

Comment: Hi,thanks, can I ask one more question? now I get this idName(=timelineKeys[t]), and I put it into jquery: $("#"+idName).css(...), but it didn't work, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Seems fine, provided you wrote `idName = timelineKeys[t]`, if you still have problems I think you should create a new question