# JQuery: Object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let `a = {a: 1, b:2}`, whichs shows in console `Object {a: 1, b: 2}`.

When I do `a.a` I get 1.
When I do `a[a]` I get undefined.

Is it normal ?

I'm asking this because I need to get values from dynamic keys. `a[product1], a[product2]....`

Comment: `a.a` is getting property `a` of object `a`.  `a[a]` is trying to get an array element.

Comment: @Archer Thanks, but how I get the property a dynamically?

Comment: @Archer - No. The former is getting the property `a` the latter is getting the property with the name that is the same as the string value of `a`. It has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: The accepted answer in the following question has a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation/

Comment: If your keys are a numeric sequence, then you should be using an array (`{ product: [val, val, val] }`) and a `for i=1; i<array.length; i++` loop.

Comment: @Quentin I never knew that - thanks :)  However, it *could* be an array so to dismiss it completely was incorrect.  Thanks for the new thing for the day though.  Name/Value pairs in JS made easy!

Comment: @Archer — Arrays are a kind of object. I mean that there was nothing special about arrays for this. It applies to any kind of object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

`a[a]` is the same as `a[a.toString()]` which is the same as `a['[object Object]']` and you haven't defined a property with that name in the object.

If you want to use square bracket notation to access a property called `a` then you have to pass a *string* with the value `a`: `a['a']` or `var prop = 'a'; a[prop]`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `a['a']` this will return the value of `a`

Answer (score 1):

try giving like this `a["a"]` or `a["product1"]`