# accessing javascript object from function

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Why does first work and not the latter?? *its only a minor difference where in the latter case i used the shorthand for accessing cats object property. I read that it shouldn't make any difference if "name of the property would be a valid variable name ― when it doesn't have any spaces or symbols in it and does not start with a digit character."

```
    //this works 
    var cats = {Spot:true};

    function addCat (name) {   cats[name] = true; }

    addCat("white");

    console.log ("white" in cats);  //true

    console.log (cats.white); //true
```

---

```
    //this doesn't work 
    var cats = {Spot:true};

    function addCat (name) {   cats.name = true; }

    addCat("white");

    console.log ("white" in cats); //false

    console.log (cats.white); //undefined
```

Comment: `cats.name` is not dynamic.

Comment: Try `console.log(cats)` and you'll see your problem

Comment: `cats.name` sets a property called `'name'` on `cats`.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Difference between using bracket (`[]`) and dot (`.`) notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17189642/218196)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second code, `cats.name` is not dynamic so your not getting the value of `name` in the function; however, you are setting a property called `name`:

```
//this works
var cats = {
    Spot: true
};

function addCat (name) {   
    cats.name = true; 
    // use cats[name] like in your first example
}
addCat("white");

console.log(cats); 
/*
{
    Spot: true,
    name: true
}
*/

console.log ("name" in cats); //true
console.log (cats.name); // true
```