# Accessing AngularJS constants

Tags: javascript, angularjs, associative-array

I have the following constant in my AngularJS app and want to access its values using the function shown below. Problem is that I pass the key as string but obviously as shown in the code below it returns undefined, so I was wondering is there a way I can convert the string passed to constant key in order to return the correct constant value corresponding to the key being passed? Thanks

```
myApp.constant('clients', {
    clientData: "clientDetails",
    clientList: "clients" });


getConstV : function(Key){
      //this one returns clientDetails
      console.log(clients.clientData);           

      //This one FAIL...returns undefined   
      console.log(clients.Key);            
    }
```

How I call getConstE is as follows:

```
   getConstV('clientDetails');
```

Comment: Mmh...what if you try to write console.log(clients[key]) instead of console.log(clients.key)?

Comment: @superpuccio to accept your answer (which is correct) you must post it as an answer, can you do so?

Comment: I tried to answer as clearly as possible, I'm glad that I have helped you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not an AngularJS problem, but a Javascript issue: in Javascript you can access the associative arrays in two ways: one is the dotted notation `array.key` and the other is the bracket notation `array[key]`. If you use the dotted notation, Javascript try to access the property with name `key` inside the associative array. In your object, though, there isn't an attribute with that name and you obtain `undefined`. On the contrary, the bracket notation lets you decide how to access the associative array (with a `constant` or a `variable`). To recap: this notation

```
array["key"]
```

produces the same result as

```
array.key
```

but if you want a flexible solution (using a variable) you must use the bracket notation this way

```
array[key]
```

where `key` is, clearly, a variable.

[Difference between using bracket (`[]`) and dot (`.`) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation)

Answer (score 1):

Did you inject your `clients` constant?

```
angular.module('myAngularApp')
    .factory('MyService', function (clients) {
        ...
        function getConstV (Key){
            console.log(clients.clientData);   
        }  
        ...              
    }
}
```