# coffeescript: get the value of an object's property starting with '@' symbol

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript

How can I get the value of a object in coffeescript:
{text="mytext", @name="Jon"}

object.text works great but can`t get object.@name and is a 3party api json object (ebay api for example use a attribute name with @ for currency_Id), what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what's called `'Bracket notation'`

```
object['@name']
```

You should use this method when: (taken from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17189764/2460773) answer)

> The property name contains characters not permitted in identifiers,
>   e.g. starts with a digit†, or contains a space or dash (-), e.g.
>   obj["my property"].

You can read up on the topic [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to acceess properties like this:

```
obj['@name']
```