# Not displaying object item which contains `.` in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Following JSON item not displaying in angularjs.

```
error = {
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "salary.salary_id": [
        "The salary.salary id field is required."
    ]
}
```

When I am trying to display error using angularjs,

```
{{error.name[0]}}
```

output will be `The name field is required`.

When I am trying to display second one,

```
{{error.salary.salary_id[0]}}
```

It display nothing, I hope the problem with `.` operator placed in key name.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[]` notation whenever your object `key` contain special characters.

```
{{error['salary.salary_id'][0]}}
```

When you use `{{error.salary.salary_id[0]}}` to get the value, it will search for the key of `salary` inside `error` and then try to find the `salary_id` inside the `salary` key, which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```
{{error['salary.salary_id'][0]}}
```

Check: [bracket vs dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation)

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem of java developers to put dots in element's id properties in javascript / html. It causes a lot of conflicts and problems. You can read it like an array (`error['salary.salary_id']`) but you will get more problems in future (in CSS, dots are styling classes).

Please, note that my intention is that you can avoid dots in ids.

Good luck.

Comment: but it will grouping all kind of items together as `json`.

Comment: It's not a reason. All of us can group all kind of elements in a json and it's not necessary to put dots in ids. This is not a correct id: `<div id="salary.salary_id">` . You can give it a lot of wheels, but is a cruft, a crap, a bad practice, an incorrect method of identify in html. Web is not java.

Comment: Thank you for reply,meanwhile I am using angularjs,then it will be a problem?

Comment: No, angularjs is not the problem. Take it easy, I don't want to cause you a problem, not at all, but I need to advice because I see a lot of issues and errors that I might to solve, because java developers have this behaviour, inserting dots in ids. If you try to avoid this practice, you can develop web with less errors