# What's this JavaScript syntax with the "$" and "[]"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery. The code snippet as below. I don't understand the syntax of the last statement.

- Why there's no `.`?
- what does the `[]` mean?
- BTW, what's special with the `$`?

  ```
  /* Code provided for context, irrelevant to the actual question.
    $('#executeButton').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('done');
    $('.done #controls :radio').attr('disabled',true);
    var sources$ = $('#sourcePane input:checked~img');
    if ($('[name=clone]:checked').val()=='yes') sources$ = sources$.clone();
    var targets$ = $('#targetPane input:checkbox:checked').parents('.target');
    var operation = $('[name=operations]:checked').val();*/
    targets$[operation](sources$); //<=== HERE
  /*});*/
  ```

  And some more context:

  ```
      <div>
        <label>Operation:</label><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="operations" value="append" checked="checked"/> append
        <input type="radio" name="operations" value="prepend"/> prepend
        <input type="radio" name="operations" value="before"/> before
        <input type="radio" name="operations" value="after"/> after
      </div>
  ```

Comment: The variable name can also contain `$`.

Comment: `targets$` is a variable name having `$`.

Comment: The variable names most likely have had a `$` put in it to indicate that the variable contains a jQuery object.

Comment: Let's see this line:

    `targets$[operation](sources$);`

The `targets$` and `sources$` are simply variables. `$` is a valid character that can be used anywhere in the variable, like how you can use `S`. Changing them to `targetsS` or `sourcesS` mean the same.

The `targets$[operation]` is an array index. The `targets$` is already an array that selects all the checked checkbox containing `.target`.

Comment: window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;   in short its a alias to call jQuery function

on the other hand , targets$ is just  fancy variable name because you can have special character in your variable names it doesnot realates to jquery function

Comment: Nothing weird here. That's ordinary jQuery, "$" sign can be used in variables like any other character, as long as it's not the first one. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/b2La2Lfr/) for example

Comment: May be this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the [] mean?

`[]` is a special javascript property access notation . imagine if i have an ojbect like:

```
var o =  {
   "abc.xyz" : 5
};
```

I can't say `o.abc.xyz` , that's where `[]` is handy `o['abc.xyz']`.

> What's special with the $?

`$` is often used as a naming convention with jquery for examle:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: I only see a wrapset method invoked with a `.` like `$(*).append(...)`. I didn't know that it can be called like this `$(*)[append](...)`.

Comment: @smwikipedia: in `$(*)[append](...)`, `append` is a variable name. This works, for example: `var a = "append"; $("*")[a]()`. The variable should contain the function's _name_.

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess you mean `$('*')['append'](...)` or `var a = 'append'; $('*')[a](...)`.

Comment: `[a]`, indeed. Whoops.

Comment: My confusion is not caused by something like `$('[name=x]')`. I am just not fully *adjusted* to the syntax to invoke a method as a property with `[]`. Well I think that's forgivable after only 2 day's crash learning of jQuery without any JS experience. This answer catches my pain point. At the price of so many down-votes, I guess it won't be easily forgotten. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see this line:

```
targets$[operation](sources$);
```

The `targets$` and `sources$` are simply variables. `$` is a valid character that can be used anywhere in the variable, like how you can use `S`. Changing them to `targetsS` or `sourcesS` mean the same.

The `targets$[operation]` is an array index. The `targets$` is already an array that selects all the checked checkbox containing `.target`.