# why gunicorn sends HTTP 500 for json request which formed using obj[attr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gunicorn

I want to know what is the different between `obj.attr` and `obj["attr"]`.

Reasoning i am asking this question is, in one of the project i worked, we were invoking a post Rest API to send data in json format. Every time we used `obj["attr"]` to prepare json request and send to* backend server (gunicorn)*, Server replied with **HTTP 500** 291 error code. and when used `obj.attr=value` to prepare json request it worked.

when i replaced backend server of gunicorn with nodejs/SOAP Mockserver it worked

Comment: `obj["attr"]` is equal to `obj.attr` but `obj[attr]` is not same as `obj.attr`

Comment: You should provide a complete example in code that reproduces the issue. Otherwise, it is very unlikely that this question can be answered as written.

Comment: Post the request data going to server in both of your case?

Comment: There are 2 answers on the same line but not specific to you question. May be you can get some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation