# How to use getJSON, function(data) with an variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Is it possible to define a variable in the $.getJSON function for example:

```
   // globale Variable - Kooperationspartner - landingpage
var KoopP = 'rabatttrend_bankaustria';
function schlaustrom_trend_preise_landingpage_bankaustria_privat_gas01() {
        $(".someSpinnerImage").show();
        $.getJSON('http://localhost-schlaustrom-ist/schlaustr_ist/images/javascript/monatsdata.json', function(data) {
                // Beginn Überschrift Preistabelle
                // Preistabelle Trendpreise Ende
                var uberschrift_trend_strom02 = document.getElementById("uberschrift_trend_strom02");
                var aktueller_monat = data.AktuellerMonat.monat;
                var aktuelles_jahr = data.AktuellesJahr.jahr;
                uberschrift_trend_strom02.innerHTML += aktueller_monat + " " + aktuelles_jahr;
                // Überschrift Ende-------------
                // Preistabelle Trendpreise Beginn ------------------------------------------------------------
                //Preis Privat -----------------------------------------
                var masterpreis01 = data.trendmaster.monatspreis.privat;
                var rabatt_prozent01 = data.obj['KoopP'].prozent.stromprivat;
                var prozent_faktor01 = (100 - rabatt_prozent01) / 100;
                var endpreis_strom_exklusive = masterpreis01 * prozent_faktor01;
                var endpreis_strom_inklusive = endpreis_strom_exklusive * 1.2;
```

...
                    // Elemente Strom ------
                    var text_trend = document.getElementById("trend_text");
                    // Ausgabe ------

```
                text_trend.innerHTML += "Sparen Sie gegenüber dem bestehenden Standardtarifen <sup> *)</sup>&nbsp; in Oberösterreich über " + Math.floor(ersparnis_strom_prozent) +"% beim Strom und über " + Math.floor(ersparnis_gas_prozent) + "% beim Gas. Ein Familienhaushalt mit " + strommenge + " kWh Strom und " + gasmenge + " kWh Gas spart so ganz einfach rund € " + gesamtersparnis.toFixed(0).toString().replace(".", ",") + ",- brutto pro Jahr.";

                // Berechnung Ersparnis Ende ----------------------------------
                $(".someSpinnerImage").fadeOut( "slow" );



    });

        }
```

data.rabattrend_bankaustria.prozent.stromprivat

here I need a variable for `rabattrend_bankaustria`. Thank Your for Your Help

Comment: Seems you are looking for `data[KoopP]` even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation can help

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Your need is not clear !

Comment: Thank's for your reply.
But 
var rabatt_prozent01 = data.obj[KoopP].prozent.stromprivat;
does nothing.

Comment: data[variable] was the trick, Thank's