# Angular - how to concat var name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, dynamic, concatenation

I just started to learn Angular, and I tried to make concat var name so I can control it dynamically.

This is what I tried -

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-click="myFunc(1)">Click Me!</button>

<div ng-show="showMe1">
    <h1>Menu:</h1>
    <div>Pizza</div>
    <div>Pasta</div>
    <div>Pesce</div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showMe1 = false;
    $scope.myFunc = function(x) {
        var nametocng = 'showMe'+x;
        //var nametocng = $parse("showMe"+x);  // - I tried this also
        $scope.nametocng = !$scope.nametocng;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the result you want? I didn't get it.

Comment: In the end, I want to make multiple Toggles, but I want one function for all of them. and then, every button will handle one toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$scope[variable]` for dynamic.

**From your comment:** *In the end, I want to make multiple Toggles, but I want one function for all of them. and then, every button will handle one toggle*

You can use `ng-repeat` for `button` to handle different menu's

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-repeat="button in array"  ng-click="myFunc(button)">Click Me!</button>

<div ng-show="showMe1">
    <h1>Menu:</h1>
    <div>Pizza1</div>
    <div>Pasta1</div>
    <div>Pesce1</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="showMe2">
    <h1>Menu:</h1>
    <div>Pizza2</div>
    <div>Pasta2</div>
    <div>Pesce2</div>
</div>
{{nametocng}}

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [1,2];
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
     
    $scope.myFunc = function(x) {
     angular.forEach($scope.array, function(value, key){
       $scope['showMe'+value] = false
});
        var nametocng = 'showMe'+x;
        //var nametocng = $parse("showMe"+x);  // - I tried this also
        $scope[nametocng] = !$scope[nametocng];
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[Here is a **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/orDzqBsI8L008k4HZV4L?p=preview)

Comment: How can I make it toggle just one? I mena - if I press the 1st and then the 2nd - the 1st will fold

Comment: Yeah, I tought about this.. but if I have a lot of toggles it will be quite long.. Isn't a way to connect between all of the toggles so they will be depends on each other?

Comment: @J.Doe, check the answer now

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dynamic variable name, you need to access via `[] syntax`. It will evaluate the variable's value and use that value as a property name.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<button ng-click="myFunc(1)">Click Me!</button>

<div ng-show="showMe1">
    <h1>Menu:</h1>
    <div>Pizza</div>
    <div>Pasta</div>
    <div>Pesce</div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showMe1 = false;
    $scope.myFunc = function(x) {
        var nametocng = 'showMe'+x;
        //var nametocng = $parse("showMe"+x);  // - I tried this also
        $scope[nametocng] = !$scope[nametocng];
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I access var with '[]' - it gives me access to the "children"-vars? Do you doc of that? It's really interesting..

Comment: I mean  - if name="bla";  so  - >  $scope[name] === $scope.bla?

Comment: Yes you are right. It evaluates the expression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

you have keep condition on click and check against concat string

**Js code**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.showMe1 = false;
      $scope.nametocng = 'showMe1';
      $scope.myFunc = function(x) {
        var nametocng = 'showMe' + x;
        $scope.showMe1 = $scope.nametocng === nametocng; // result will bool
      }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-app='myApp'>
      <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
        <button ng-click="myFunc(1)">Click Me!</button>
        {{showMe1}} {{nametocng}}
        <div ng-show="showMe1">
          <h1>Menu:</h1>
          <div>Pizza</div>
          <div>Pasta</div>
          <div>Pesce</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ppLn4xks/1/)