# Get a value from an object using a variable as a key

Tags: javascript-objects, destructuring

I have an Object like;

```
  players: {
    '1': {id:1, name:'', ....},
    '2': {id:2, name:'', ....},
     ... 
   }
```

I want to desctruct an object by its key as currentPlayer. (playernumber is passed as props).

```
const currentPlayer = Object.keys(players).filter(
      obj => obj.id === playerNumber
    );
```

this did not work, also I do not want to use `id` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between using bracket (\`\[\]\`) and dot (\`.\`) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, but I did not even know I can use [] for objects, though it is only for Array. new in JS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get a specific player is with bracket notation:

```
const currentPlayer = players[playerNumber];
```

This assumes that `playerNumber` is a valid key in the `players` object.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use `Object.values()` to achieve this?

The `Object.values()` will return the values of your `players` object (`{id:1, name:'', ....}`, etc) as an array. You can then use the `.filter()` method to select the player value by `playerNumber`.

So for instance, something like this:

```
const currentPlayer = Object.values(players).filter(
  obj => obj.id === playerNumber
);
```

You will find [that this works in most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

Alternativly, if you have your `players` object organised so that the keys are player id's, you can access a player in this way:

```
const currentPlayer = players[playerNumber];
```

Comment: Thanks, the Documentation was saying values() returns array[id,1,name,...] but it returning Object now.

Comment: how can I not use id attribute and just the key which is number. if my sub objects did not have id attr

Comment: Thanks, it is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` will give you an array of keys rather than the object stored under those keys (i.e. `Object.keys(players)` returns `['1', '2', ...]`).

If you want to get the objects, you can map the result array like so:

```
// Use map to turn the array of keys into the array of objects
const currentPlayer = Object.keys(players).map(id => players[id])
  // be careful: filter returns an array, but you probably just want the one object
  .filter(obj => obj.id === playerNumber)[0]
```

Depending on what you're targeting, you may also have access to `Object.values()` which does the same thing (i.e. you'd replace the first line with just `Object.values(players)`), just be aware that browser support is a [little more limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks yes I want only the object, so how can I avoid using the id attribute. for instance, if the keys are still numbers, but the object does not contain id number

Comment: Not clear on what you mean by avoiding using the id attribute.

Comment: Never mind, clear now from the accepted answer. Had assumed there was a specific reason you were avoiding doing it that way, rather than just not being clear on how to do it :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I am new in javascript, thinking [] is only used for arrays.